# Remove all quotation marks from a textfile string

Tags: python, string, text-files

```
def organize_data(location='G:\pythonFiles\problem 22.txt'):
    with open(location) as f:
        name_string = f.read().replace('\n', '')
        name_string.replace('"', '')
        names = name_string.split(',')
    return names

print organize_data()
```

It seems like the `replace` method isnt working, because with or without it im getting the same result: `['"MARY"', '"PATRICIA"', '"LINDA"', '"BARBARA"',.....]`

How can i remove all `"` and return a list like that: `['MARY', 'PATRICIA', 'LINDA', 'BARBARA',.....]`
``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable, so string methods can't modify a string in place.  They instead return a modified version of the string.

`name_string.replace('"', '')` as a separate statement does not do anything.  It returns the string with double quotes removed, but the return value is not stored anywhere.  So you should use

```
name_string = name_string.replace('"', '')
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use open with encoding, `name_string.replace('"', '')` means that you are working with utf-8.
Try this

```
def organize_data(location='G:\pythonFiles\problem 22.txt'):
    with open(location, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        name_string = f.read()replace('\n', '')
        name_string = name_string.replace('"', '')
        names = name_string.split(',')
    return names

print organize_data()
```